# Jquery datatable not getting editable

Tags: jquery, datatables

My jquery datatable is not getting editable..I am using simple html page

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#detailsgrid').dataTable()
      .makeEditable();
    });
```

Adding rows like this

```
 function addrow() {
        //alert("sxcsdsd");
        //jQuery('#detailsgrid').dataTable().makeEditable();
        jQuery('#detailsgrid').dataTable().fnAddData([
                          '<input id=\"Checkbox\" type =\"checkbox\" name = chk  onclick = javascript:removeRow(this)  />',
                           jQuery("#txtcasetype").val(),
                           jQuery("#txtcd").val(),
                           jQuery("#txtpatclass").val(),
                           jQuery("#txtcd1").val(),
                           jQuery("#txtresamt").val(),
                           jQuery("#txtadmamt").val()]);
    }
```

Where I am doing wrong..I have also registered required plugins

```
 <script src="jquery.dataTables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Google code files.

Demo

http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html

Download

https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/

its helps you surely.

---

Or You can use this

You can use the fnDraw function to redraw the table. Try this:

```
var $dataTable = $("#my-datatable").dataTable({ /* setup */ });

$("#refreshButton").click(function() {
    $dataTable.fnDraw();
});
```

Have a read of the fnDraw entry in the documentation.